# UIButton returns nil

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, xcode8, viewcontroller

So this is my situation: I have a class:

```
class upgrade {
    var buttonOutlet: UIButton?
init(buttonOutlet: UIButton?) {
self.buttonOutlet = buttonOutlet }
}
```

Then, I have one upgrade:

```
var upgrade1 = upgrade.init(buttonOutlet: nil)`
```

Obviously, I can't set the 'buttonOutlet' at that point.
So I have a function that sets it for me when needed:

```
func setBO() {
upgrade1.buttonOutlet?  = buttonOutletForUpgrade1
}
```

This "buttonOutletForUpgrade1" is an outlet from a button I created earlier. 
I want to be able to set the button's title after calling 'setBO'. However, it doesn't do anything!
When I run the code, my upgrade1.buttonOutlet returns nil. How can this be? Didn't I set it right? Please explain!
Thanks!

Comment: When are you calling `setBO` function?

Comment: So I have this function that changes the title of the button. In that function I first call setBO, then I change the title of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follows and it works. Tested before and after and it works.

```
func setBO() {
    upgrade1.buttonOutlet = buttonOutletForUpgrade1
}
```

Don't add a question mark at the end.